# How to grab a string before hyphen using Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

My variable is as such:

```
api-20150901r1_6.38
```

Using Jinja, I need a way to grab the string BEFORE the hyphen. There will always be one hyphen so I dont need to worry about multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `input_string` is `api-20150901r1_6.38`

You can use set

```
{% set mylist = input_string.split('-') %}
```

This is your value "api" in this case

```
{{ mylist[0] }}
```